# why the solution $X$ of the matrix equations not possible?

Tags: linear-algebra

**When I read the literature, I saw the author draw the following conclusion using the method of proof by contradiction:**

Vector variable $w\in\mathbb{R}^{(n+p)q}$. The functions $E$ and $F$ satisfy

\begin{align*}
E(w)=&E_0+\delta E\\
\text{vec}(\delta E)=&w_{1:nq}\\
F(w)=&F_0+\delta F\\
\text{vec}(\delta F)=&w_{(nq+1):(nq+pq)}
\end{align*}

where $E_0\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times q}$ and $F_0\in\mathbb{R}^{p\times q}$ are constant matrices, $w_{1:nq}$ means extracting only the first $nq$ elements of $w$, $\text{vec}(\delta E)$ means vectorization of $\delta E$.

There must exist a matrix $X(w)\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times q}$ for each $w$ such that

$\begin{align}
X(w)A_1=&AX(w)+E(w)\\
0=&CX(w)+F(w)
\end{align}$

where the constant matrices $A_1\in\mathbb{R}^{q\times q}$, $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$, $C\in\mathbb{R}^{p\times n}$.

**And the author said the conclusion was impossible because**

the equations define a surjective linear mapping $\mathcal{F}:\mathbb{R}^{n\times q}\to\mathbb{R}^{(n+p)\times q}$. But this is impossible since $n<n+p$.

**I do not understand the meaning of "equations define such mapping" and why the solution $X(w)$ for each $w$ is not possible**

Comment: What is $X$ in the first equation, did you mean $X(w)$?

Comment: Are $E$ and $F$ surjective?

Comment: $E$ and $F$ are some non-linear function of $w$, generally not surjective.

Comment: Oh, that's $X(w)$. I will edit this equation. Thank you.

Comment: Hmmm, if they are surjective, then that is easily done. Otherwise I don't see how that could be possible. Maybe you can share the title of the book, so we can check what sideconstraints we might not know/you might have overlooked.

Comment: Thank you for your serious answer, the book title is “Nonlinear Output Regulation: Theory and Applications”, and relevant content can be found on page 20 (in fact, I simplified the expression). The link to the book is [**Nonlinear Output Regulation**](https://epubs.siam.org/doi/book/10.1137/1.9780898718683?mobileUi=0). If you have trouble downloading it, I would be happy to send the DJUV File of this book to your email.

Comment: the relevant equation is eq. 1.55 on page 20.

Comment: Sorry, I found that $E$ and $F$ are linear functions, $w\in\mathbb{R}^N$, where N is a big integer. I tried to revise the wording of the problem.